# Django admin single action to return 2 csv files

Tags: python, django, csv

I have defined 2 model admin actions to retrun 2 csv files in django. Both the csvs are created and working file when called separately. How do I download both the CSV files by clicking only 1 action function. Both the CSVs have different values as desired.

Something I tried calling both the functions in another method that I use in the model action code snippet:

```
def export_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):

    queryset_f1 = queryset
    response_f1 = export_f1(modeladmin, request, queryset_f1)

    queryset_f2 = queryset
    response_f2 = export_f2(modeladmin, request, queryset_f2)

    return (response_f1,response_f2)
```

I tried calling actions = ['export_csv',] but this returns nothing. I can call either at a time, but I want both the files to be downloaded simultaneously. Using django 1.6.5

Comment: You could zip the two csv files (like Gmail etc. does when you request multiple attachments)

Answer (score 1):

A single http request can trigger only a single response. You should zip the two files, and download them zipped result.

You can easily create a zip file using [Python's zipfile library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html).

Even when you've the zipfile ready, you might want to return something else than the file as is. For the browser to provide you its download view, you need some special headers set on you HttpResponse instance. Example follows:

```
    response = HttpResponse(json_data, content_type='application/json')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="download.json"' % self.get_filename()
    return response
```

This will trigger the download window in the browser.

To get these working under the admin, is not obvious, [see the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages).

Comment: export_f1 and export_f2 are 2 different methods triggering 2 different responses!

Comment: it does not matter how many calls you make inside your admin action. There is a single admin action export_csv in your example. This means a single http request, and a single http response.